# How do I multi-entry Column Default Values in SharePoint 2013 Document Library?

Tags: column, default-value, modern-document-library

There are 12 monthly folders, one for each month. I want to set default values in each for automation operations. Current method I am using:

1. Go into the Library Setting
2. Click in Column Default Value Setting
3. Select one folder at a time and enter default values

What I want to know:

Is there a way to select all folders and enter their respective default values?

Background reference: 
I know it is easy to create multiple folders using windows command lines; by writing "md 'folderName1' 'folderName2' etc, I save time from individually creating each folder in the file explorer. I want to know if similar shortcut approach is available for managing Column Default Values in Document Library of SharePoint 2013.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no API or way that I have found to make this painful, but albeit important, process better or faster.